# Can I cancel a swingworker and wait for it to complete before running background task

Tags: java, swingworker, future, executor

Can I cancel a `Swingworker` and wait for it to complete before running background task? Or alternatively, can I send an interrupt to a task that runs the code in `doInBackground()` without cancelling the whole swing worker.?

My problem is I do not want the code in `done()` to start before the code in `doInBackground()` has completed. Earlier code never called cancel on the `Swingworker` instead I just set a volatile boolean that the `WidgetController` would check and if set closedown gracefully. This all worked fine except the `WidgetController` sometimes took to long to check this flag, so I need to be able use the interrupt method.

#### Pseudo Example

A dialog is displayed when user clicks start this invokes `WidgetDialogListener` this creates instance of `WidgetWorker`, this starts `WidgetController`, displays a `WidgetProgressDialog` and on normal completion of `WidgetController` displays `ShowWidgetReport` showing a summary of what `WidgetController` did.

Whilst the `WidgetController` is running, the `WidgetProgressDialog` is displayed showing progress. If the user clicks on the cancel button to stop progress this causes an interrupt to be sent to `WidgetController` then **without waiting for `widgetcontroller` to actually complete**  the done method gets called causing `ShowWidgetReport` to display. But I don't want it to do this until `WidgetController` has actually completed.

```
class WidgetDialogListener implements ActionListener
{
    public  WidgetDialogListener()
    {

    }

    public  void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        StartFixSongsDialog.this.dispose();
        WidgetProgressDialog wpd = new FixSongsDialog();
        wpd.setVisible(true);
        WidgetWorker ww = new WidgetWorker();
        wpd.setSwingWorker(ww);
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().submit(ww);
    }
}

   class WidgetProgressDialog
   {
      ....................

        private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Main.stopTask();
            swingWorker.cancel(true);
        }
    }

class WidgetWorker extends SwingWorker<String, Object>
{
    @Override
    public String doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
       new WidgetController().startCreateWidgets();
       return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void done()
    {
        ShowWidgetReport showReport = new ShowWidgetReport();
        showReport.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### Edit

I used the `AwaitingWorker` described at [Waiting for a cancelled future to actually finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522427/waiting-for-a-cancelled-future-to-actually-finish?rq=1) that Jacob pointed me to

```
abstract class AwaitingWorker<T, V> extends SwingWorker<T, V>
{
    private final CountDownLatch actuallyFinishedLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    protected abstract T performOperation() throws Exception;

    @Override
    protected final T doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            return performOperation();
        }
        finally
        {
            actuallyFinishedLatch.countDown();
        }
    }

    public void awaitActualCompletion() throws InterruptedException
    {
        actuallyFinishedLatch.await();
    }
}

class WidgetWorker extends AwaitingWorker<String, Object>
{
    @Override
    public String performOperation() throws Exception
    {
        new WidgetController().startCreateWidgets();
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void done()
    {
        try
        {
            awaitActualCompletion();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ioe)
        {

        }
        ShowWidgetReport showReport = new ShowWidgetReport();
        showReport.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Maybe have misunderstood exactly the solution but it seems whichever way you do it a gui thread ends up waiting for a non-gui task to finish, whereas what I want I want is for the non-gui task to complete before anything is done on the gui thread.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522427/waiting-for-a-cancelled-future-to-actually-finish?rq=1 for ideas if you haven't already.

Comment: @Paul Taylor not sure what do you really ..., can you please to [simulating your issue (just to add cancel() to the JButton)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6186188/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel hi im sorry I dont understand what you are asking me